# How to perform an idle scan against a target using Nmap with a list of zombies?

Tags: nmap, ports, network-scanners, ip-spoofing

I want to perform port scan against a target but the firewall at the target only allows traffic to the ports through certain IP address/machines. I tried to perform an idle scan in Nmap but it only takes one IP address as a zombie at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the zombies' IP addresses in a file (say `IP.txt`).
And let's assume that the target machine

> 192.168.88.135

Then you can use a script to automate the scan process.
Something like this

```
for ip in $(cat IP.txt); do  
nmap -sI $ip 192.168.88.135 -p $1 >$ip.txt
done
```

After saving this script, and giving it execution privileges, you can invoke this script and pass the port you wish to scan to it as a parameter.

For example :

```
./script.sh 80
```

This command will attempt to preform idle scan on the target for port 80 using all the zombies you had their IPs in `IP.txt` and will save the result of each scan in a text file with the zombie's IP address.

I hope i got your questions right cause i still have doubts about whether this is what you want exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Though I used ">>" to append instead. I forgot I could use the scripts.